# create priced magento order without paying

Tags: magento

any help would be appreciated.

I need to create a 2 orders on products that are $100 per order.  I need to create these orders but would like to do so without having to actually pay for the order.  I know I can apply a coupon to force it to $0, but I actually want the reflected price to be $100.

Is there any way to manually create these in magento while reflecting the full price, and without having to go through the payment gateway or entering in a credit card on the create orders page?

Thank you!

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, focus on point #3

Comment: Thanks Dave - will be more conscious of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable an offline payment method and use that. Like 'Check / Money order'. If you want this only available in the backend override the class `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Checkmo` and add this line `protected $_canUseCheckout = false;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict this to back-end only, i.e. not letting online customers choose this option, then the Check / Money Order payment method is the way to go. However you need to tweak the code slightly. Follow this tutorial:

http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento-how-to-place-an-order-for-free-using-free-payment-option-in-admin.html

Take note to save the new file in the app/code/local folder and not app/code/core.

Basically you'll leave check and order visible on backend only.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Will this display the Grand Total as $0.00?  I need it to actually display a Grand Total of $100 in the magento admin console for Orders.

Comment: Yes it will, it just treats payment as check / money order, all the order details will remain the same!